# Apache mod_rewrite recursing

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need help.
I've wasted half hour to get my `mod_rewrite` rule. Unsuccessfully.

My server root structure is:

```
/project/public_html/index.html
/project/public_html/css/style.css
/project/public_html/js/script.js
```

I want to access it from my localhost as:

```
/project/index.html
/project/css/style.css
/project/js/script.js
```

I have this in my `/project/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /project
RewriteRule    ^(.+)$ public_html/$1    [L,QSA,NS]
```

But I'm still getting this:

```
[Thu Dec 05 12:29:20.252091 2013] [core:error] [pid 26176] [client 127.0.0.1:60642] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

And actually is happening this:

```
[Thu Dec 05 12:29:20.252111 2013] [core:debug] [pid 26176] core.c(3520): [client 127.0.0.1:60642] AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /project/public_html/public_html/public_html/public_html/public_html/public_html/public_html/public_html/public_html/index.html
```

Problem should be extremely simple, but neither Google, nor manual helped me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `^(.*)$` matches what you rewrite it to too. You'll need to make sure the rewritten url doesn't match your rule again.

Comment: Yeah, obviously, but I was unable to write the condition. Thanks to @anubhava, now works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule with **an additional condition to stop looping**. This condition first checks whether `/public_html` has already been inserted into request URI.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /project/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public_html/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public_html/$1 [L,NS]
```